# Sizing issues while adding a .Net UserControl to a TabPage

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, tabpage

I have a complex Windows Forms GUI program that has a lot of automated control generation and manipulation. One thing that I need to be able to do is add a custom UserControl to a newly instatiated TabPage. However, when my code does this I get automatic resizing events that cause the formatting to get ugly. Without detailing all of the different Containers that could possibly be involved, the basic issue is this:

At a certain point in the code I create a new tab page:

```
TabPage tempTabPage = new TabPage("A New Tab Page");
```

Then I set it to a certain size that I want it to maintain:

```
tempTabPage.Width = 1008;
tempTabPage.Height = 621;
```

Then I add it to a TabControl:

```
tabControl.TabPages.Add(tempTabPage);
```

Then I create a user control that I want to appear in the newly added TabPage:

```
CustomView customView = new CustomView("A new custom control");
```

Here is where the problem comes in. At this point both the tempTabPage and the customView are the same size with no padding or margin and they are the size I want them to be. I now try to add this new custom UserControl to the tab page like this:

```
tempTabPage.Controls.Add(customView);
```

When making this call the customView and it's children controls get resized to be larger and so parts of the customView are hidden.

Can anyone give me any direction on what to look for or what could be causing this kind of issue?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 14):

The UserControl's "AutoScaleMode" property should be set to "None".

Comment: Your answer just helped me in a completely different topic. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

If you want the `customView` to fill the `TabPage`.

Use `Dock` like this:

```
tempTabPage.Controls.Add(customView);
customView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Then the `customView` will fill out the space in the `TabPage`, but you have to handle resizing of the `customView` so child controls will be shown properly.

Comment: This worked for me (have the UserControl resize automatically). The AutoScaleMode=None did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
The UserControl's "AutoScaleMode" set to "None" works for me.