# Custom UserControls automatically resizes when hosted on a WinForm form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, custom-controls

I've a problem with my WinForm application.
I'm using a Tab Control where i put a custom usercontrol in every tab panel (tab panel 1 contains a custom usercontrol, tab panel 2 an another one, etc).

My custom usercontrols have specified size, but when I add my custom usercontrol to an another usercontrol or when I run the application, them are bigger than in design mode...it seems that the hosting Form zooms hosted usercontrols, but I have no idea why this happens..

Another problem is that distances between items are corrupted.

Here is an example:

Three combos (hosted in a hosted usercontrol) in design mode:

[image]

And the same three combos when I'm running the program or when I simply add
my custom usercontrol to a window/form:

[image]

As you can see they are bigger and the distance between them changes...

This is happening on most of hosted controls (but not all), without a logic...

What can it be? I'm optimizing the application to run on specified-size screens but I can't do this with these problems...

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe there are some weird things happening on Form_Load ?

Comment: What are their anchors?

Comment: In the ctor of the UserControl, subscribe to the event `SizeChanged` of the controls with a method that does nothing, put a breakpoint in there and run. Check the call stack to get an idea of whats going on.

Comment: No size changed called :/ I've discovered that the "zoom problem" is also in design mode, when i put my custom usercontrol inside an another and not only at runtime...

Answer (score 2):

I've found an another user with the same problem only now :
[Sizing issues while adding a .Net UserControl to a TabPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733521/sizing-issues-while-adding-a-net-usercontrol-to-a-tabpage)

The problem is on a property not visible in design mode: you have to change the property AutoScaleMode to None, on usercontrol's designer:

```
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None;
```

Comment: I believe AutoScalemode only works when AutoSize is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Very late reply, but hopefully this will help someone out there who's run into this same problem and couldn't find a solution, like I just did.

What worked for me was to set `AutoScaleMode` to `Inherit` in the user control's designer.
`AutoSize` was set to `false`, though I don't know if that had any effect.